# Framelayout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have try to create layout using Framelayout .

Below code which I try but dont get output . I want output like images.

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:src="@drawable/login_arrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/login_fbsignup" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: So what is the current result?

Comment: First image is in top|left and second is in bottom|right of screen

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`. But even more, I'd just make one image and use without any layout container

Comment: Yes, But I want put on click on sign up button , so I can not use one image

Comment: but when output is in different resolution mobile , Its may not same

Comment: If you overlay both images and then use margin / padding to position and you use `dp` then you should end with the same look